# L.E.Ds bright enough for stage lighting?

Tags: led, led-driver, lighting

Can anyone tell me what power level one would need for LEDs meant to light stages, or point me at how to figure that out from product descriptions?

Edit for more info, I'm wanting to make wide throw footlights that will be between about 5 and 15 feet from the performers. Sorry for the vagueness, I'm a total noob to lighting.

Comment: Find out what you currently use for the job, find it's datasheet and make a note of the electrical characteristics such as voltage, current, lumens (or candelas), collimation (or spread) angles and so forth.  Then use those specs to find an LED counterpart.

Comment: Something like 20% of the incandescent equivalent: https://www.thomann.de/gb/stairville_revueled_120_cob_3200k_dmx.htm

Comment: What kind of brightness are you looking for? Angle? Throw? Type of light? A lot of missing info.

Comment: Why not go look at the plethora of LED stage lights already on the market and see what's common?

Answer (score 0):

- typical, 50-300W per light
- with 15-25deg glass focal lens
- ~80 Lumens/W

  - (depends on loss in lens from >120LPW and more loss with narrow beam)
- 5000'K, CW or 3500'K WW
- flicker free for TV video,
- with remote dimmer. DMX512
- 20deg glass focal lens depends on spot or flood

  - ... $5-10$/W depends on mechanical quality, extra bells and whistles.
- CRI around 85
- quiet heatpipe cooling with fan
- optional lenses from 4 deg to 50 deg, elliptical quad lamps

Comment: actual Lumens/square meter depends on stage height inverse squared loss and desired intensity

Comment: For the OP: CRI of around 85 is probably what you will find. Technically, higher CRI would be fine, too. So 85 is kind of like the approximate minimum.

Comment: It's also an approximate maximum due to phospor limitations ~ CRI~86, 90 is not possible.